# DSLR mirror stuck at top, sound like rolling gears

Tags: nikon, dslr, repair, error, mirror

[image]I have Nikon D300, and now its mirror stuck at top, showing 'Err' at top display. It happens when I press shutter button, it sounds like rolling gear.
I still can press the shutter but looks like the gear isn't attached.

Does it hits its lifetime? (still I hope it can be fixed) What can I do to fix it? 
Thanks for your responses.

Comment: It is broken. If you don't know how to fix it you need to take it or send it to someone who does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper answer is "Send it to Nikon or an authorized repair facility". It will be expensive to fix, and may exceed the value of the camera (to you), but they will give you an estimate first and you can decide if it is worth fixing. You can try calling first and describing the issue and they may (or may not be willing to) give you a "no less than $x" cost based on what they observe, but as with any repair they may find additional issues.

You could try gently seeing if your finger will allow the mirror to release, tug on it a bit. ***This may do more damage***, and it is doubtful it will solve the issue, but I did have a camera once that due to a blow the mirror jammed up, but worked perfectly after being released with a gentle nudge. Don't count on that working however, but if the choice is writing off the camera, it may be worth trying.

Comment: actually this is what I've done. sent it to Nikon Service Center, since it is an old camera. they replaced the shutter gear. thank you

Answer (score 2):

If none of the internet advises work and you don’t want to spend a ton of money try this on a D300s:
If the mirror keeps getting stuck, set the camera to Quiet mode. The mechanism for quiet mode is separate from the normal fast mirror release and is designed to move the mirror back into place softly. So basically there are two modes, one is failing to operate correctly so use the other - plan B. This trick has worked for me. Best luck

Answer (score 1):

Take out the battery for overnight. Put the battery back in and half press the shutter button and see if that releases the mirror. This is very common on the 300/300s cameras. Also there is a reset button on the black rubber on the botton of the camera. Sometimes pressing that (somehow) will totally reset the camera.
280 and up for nikon to fix.